# How can i open a new email website or app on click of a button?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, button

Please who can help me out I need my button to open up a new tab to the email website or on the email app on phone.
I've been seeing the `Mailto` but i specifically need the Email(Gmail, Yahoo, Outlook etc.) to open at inbox and not as a new mail to be sent.

Comment: There is no way to do that.

Comment: In theory if the mail app on the phone has registered a domain name to be triggered you could send them to the website of the service and the appropriate app will open. It doesn't always work though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not really a a way of opening an app with html but you can open the email in a new tab:

```
<button onclick="window.open('https://gmail.com')">Gmail</button>
```

Or you can put it in a popup if you need:

```
<button onclick="window.open('https://gmail.com','popup','width=600,height=600')">Gmail</button>
```